# What is this spinning object seen on a spacecraft above the ISS?

Tags: iss, antenna, identify-this-object

In the [YouTube Trailer](https://youtu.be/ugl8q8btMAs?t=56) for the PBS program [A Year in Space](http://www.pbs.org/a-year-in-space/home/?utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=pbsofficial&utm_campaign=beyondyearinspace_2017) at `00:56` a small spinning object can be seen, attached to *a spacecraft well above* the ISS. I think the video is significantly speeded up so the object looks blurred.

It reminds me a bit of the [RapidScat](https://winds.jpl.nasa.gov/missions/RapidScat/) (shown below), a microwave scatterometer that measures near-surface wind speed and direction, mentioned [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16569/12102) and explained [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/8742/12102).

Is this an antenna of some kind or something else? What spacecraft is it attached to?

**below:** RapidScat

[image: RapidScat]

**below:** GIF from the [YouTube Trailer](https://youtu.be/ugl8q8btMAs?t=56) at about `00:56`. The motion is clearer in the original video linked below it.

[image: GIF from video]

Comment: In your 2nd image, why do you say the spinning object is attached to the ISS? The whole ISS is visible far away.  The spinning object appears to be mounted on the Soyuz.

Comment: @OrganicMarble a minor detail (blush). I'll rewrite and try to be more careful when posting after midnight in the future.

Comment: Why don't you think it's a RapidScat?

Comment: @RonJohn I don't any more, thanks. I've recently updated the question; now I only mention now that it *reminds me* of the RapidScat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the "Kurs system 2AO" antenna on a Soyuz. It measures line-of-sight heading and pitch angles.

Sources

- [Modelling of Soyuz Docking and Radar Systems
  for Implementation in the IRS Simulator](http://orbit.medphys.ucl.ac.uk/press/DA_Schlottke.pdf)
- [Obsolete NASA page on Kurs](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/expeditions/expedition14/kurs_antenna_system.html)
- Personal notes

Answer (score 7):

This is a rotating antenna, part of the Kurs docking system on Soyuz and Progress spacecraft

[See e.g. This video of a docking](https://youtu.be/CoLRdl4bzsw)

Comment: Excellent video, thank you for the answer! If you are so inclined, [How many antennas does Kurz use in toto, and what are each of their functions?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22041/12102) is in need of an answer. I've just added a bounty to it.